# Reading QR Code in an image with zxing

Tags: c#, qr-code, zxing

I'm using a C# library for reading of QRCodes.  A lot of the samples I've found are based off the old version of zxing where the RGBLuminanceSource constructor still takes in bitmap.  In the latest version RGBLuminanceSource only takes byte[].  I've tried to convert bitmap to byte[], but the decode result is always null.

Here's the code I used for conversion:

```
private byte[] GetRGBValues(Bitmap bmp)
{
  // Lock the bitmap's bits. 
  System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
  System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

  // Get the address of the first line.
  IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

  // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
  int bytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;
  byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
  // Copy the RGB values into the array.
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
  bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

  return rgbValues;
}
```

and for decode:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\QRimages.jpg") as Bitmap;
LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(GetRGBValues(bitmap), bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(source);
var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
QRCodeReader reader = new QRCodeReader();
var result = reader.decode(binBitmap);
```

Somehow the result is always null.

Also, our requirement is that we have to use image taken by camera.  I've tried this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\QRimages.jpg") as Bitmap;
BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader { AutoRotate = true, TryHarder = true };
Result result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
```

It only works for the QR image I download online, but if I print out that image and take a picture of that with my phone, then try to process that image, the result is back to null.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here's the image I'm using: [image: QR Code Image]

Comment: Hey, same thing here. Did you ever solve this problem?